# deeplink to chat in microsoft teams app tab not working

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a `microsoft teams` app. I'm working on creating a `deeplink` in `microsoft teams` from a tab in the app that goes back to the chat and it doesn't seem to be working.

It seems even if I point it the chat, when using deep links, it hides the chat and defaults it the the "files" tab

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/app-id/app goes to the app tab
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/app-id/contact goes to the contact tab
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/app-id/about goes to the about tab

but

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/app-id/chat goes to the files tab and the chat tab disappears

We are also aware that there is a current issue where using a deeplink hides the chat link so this could be related.

Documentation I'm using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links

Comment: We are able to reproduced the issue and raised a bug . We don't have any ETA to share.